# Regex - Checking if [x]/[y] y is greater than x

Tags: awk

I'm trying to capture [x]/[y] and if y is greater than x using a regex pattern.
The input is in the second column ($2)

Example input:

```
NAME1 0/1
NAME2 0/2
NAME3 1/2
NAME4 1/3
NAME5 2/2
NAME6 1/1
```

Output:

```
NAME1 0/1
NAME2 0/2
NAME3 1/2
NAME4 1/3
```

What would be the right approach using awk?

I've done so far:

```
cat pods | grep -v Completed | awk -e '$2 ~ "[0-9]/[0-9]"'
```

I'm not sure how to proceed or to check if the second [0-9] is greater.

Comment: My impression is however, that a regex is the wrong approach to a mathmatical, i.e. value-based, attribute of text.

Comment: Your own attempt shows that you are fine with single digit values being the scope. For that you might get away with basically checking for all possible text representations, i.e. without actually understanding the "greater than" realtionship of numeric values. Because I still think the answer should be "wrong tool".

Comment: Regular expressions cannot test numeric value of the strings they match. You need to use an actual programming language.

Comment: Please provide sample input which represents your problem. "This is the second column." makes providing solutions harder.

Comment: @TomS awk can do numeric comparisons, it's not tied to regexps.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

With your shown samples, please try following `awk` code. Simple explanation would be, in main program splitting 2nd field using `awk`'s `split` function and splitting 2nd field into array named `arr` using field separator `/`, then checking condition if 2nd element of array is GREATER than 1st element then printing that line.

```
awk  '{split($2,arr,"/")} arr[2]>arr[1]' Input_file
```

***OR*** As an alternate solution one could also use:

```
awk -F' |/' '$3>$2' Input_file
```

Comment: $1 is the first column with the names, $2 has the 0/1, 0/2 etc..

Comment: ... and you made that clear in the sample input you provided..... ? @TomS

Comment: @TomS, ok sure, then I have changed my code as per your comment, please edit your question also with same, thank you.

Comment: Added to the question. Thanks so much, it works very well.

Comment: I didn't know awk had "split", i'll read about it

Comment: @TomS, Your welcome, request you to please do add samples where 1st field is names and 2nd field is 0/1 like values that will help future users to understand question better, thank you.

Comment: Fixed now, added the first column

Answer (score 3):

A bit shorter `gnu awk` using `/` as field separator:

```sh
awk -F/ '$2 > gensub(/.* /, "", "1", $1)+0' file

NAME1 0/1
NAME1 0/2
NAME1 1/2
NAME1 1/3
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to match the pattern with digits and a forward slash, another option using `gnu awk` using a pattern with 2 capture groups, matching 1 or more digits using `([0-9]+)` on the left and right of `/`

The values of the capture groups are in array `a` which you can use to compare group 2 with group 1.

```
awk 'match($2, "^([0-9]+)/([0-9]+)$", a) {
  if(a[2]>a[1]) print
}' file
```

Output

```
NAME1 0/1
NAME2 0/2
NAME3 1/2
NAME4 1/3
```

---

Using `awk` you can match the pattern and then split on the forward slash

```
awk '$2 ~ "^[0-9]+/[0-9]+$" {
  split($2,a,"/")
  if(a[2]>a[1]) print
}' file
```